# How to make sure to get sets of n rows in MySQL regardless of ID?

Tags: mysql

Right now I have the last ten rows using

```
SELECT col, col1, col2
FROM tabytle
ORDER BY ID DESC
limit 10
```

That works even with the gap of the latest ID having a value of 67 and the next entry having an ID value of 27.

With that in mind, if I were to hit "next" how would I get the next 10 rows which may not start with the ID of 18.

Should I count rows? And just loop/find rows till I get 10 unique IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the offset parameter in `limit`

```
SELECT *
FROM tabytle 
ORDER BY ID DESC 
limit 10, 10
```

to get the next 10 records.

Comment: Thanks I will try this. Do you think that it is not the right way to keep track of what last rows I have by saving a local variable and use that with Javascript. Say the last ten set was 20 to 30, and I wanted the next ten being 31-41, I would have a variable that has the 30 value and I would use that to say "start from 30, get the next ten rows"

Comment: That is fine. Use the variable as offset in your queries to get next records.

Comment: Actually I think I know how to do it. You'd send a different value for the offset parameter, like 20,30,40, etc... thanks. If there aren't 10 records, MySQL will return whatever is there?

Comment: I actually got it backwards, the first part is the offset, limit 20, would start at 21st row, not the other way around where limit 10, 20, would start at 10, and give you 20 results... huh... I guess limit 10, 0 is actually start at 10, return 0 results?